# How to get the position of scrollbar thumb

Tags: winapi

I am trying to build a *custom-scrollbar* with winapi

[image: example]

To get Thumb length :

**B / A = D / C**

**D = C * B / A**

All fine so far. but struggling to find the Thumb position

[image: example]

Given an (viewport) offset, how to get the thumb offset?
Or any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your thumb size calculation contains an error - rearranging valid proportion `A / B = C / D`, thumb size is `D = C * B / A`, not `D = C * A / B`.
Regarding offset calculation, proportion can be constructed in a similar way since track `C` represents whole content `A` and thumb offset `F` represents viewport offset `E`. So, `A / C = E / F`, from which, rearranging, we get `F = E * C / A`.

Comment: I think you're missing that thumb has nonzero length, therefore `F` shouldn't go all the way to `A` as your formula suggests.

Comment: @lorro As far as I understand, scroll track has 3 parts - before thumb (size of which is exactly the offset `F`), thumb (`D`) and after thumb (`C - F - D`), which are proportional to before viewport (`E`), viewport (`B`) and after viewport (`A - E - B`) parts of content. Proportionality constant is `C / A`, which is reflected by my formulas.

Comment: Thanks for explaining to me the concept in detail

Comment: @YurkoFlisk gotcha, my bad. If you edit a character in the orig post, I can remove the downvote.